Path with special characters
If there are special characters, namely Cyrillic letters, in directories in the project path, the simulation ends with an error "Re: Compilation process failed. Exited with code 0x00000002.".
I'm using the version OpenModelica 1.22.2-64bit.
How can I solve this problem if there is no way to exclude special characters from in the project path.
When excluding special characters, the simulation runs without errors, but I am considering the case where it is not possible to change the path.
A similar problem existed here earlier, in particular here. I would like to know if this problem has been resolved at the moment.

Are you on Windows or Linux? The bug is known and depending on the C compiler tool-chain.

Windows. Is there no such problem for Linux?

No, it has to do with the MSYS and MINGW make executable used on Windows. In a nutshell the one used by OpenModelica can't handle wide characters correctly when called from CMD.
On Linux there is only one make which can handle them. For more details check the issue I mentioned below.

You encountered a known bug: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/9402.
OpenModelica on Windows ships with MSYS2 to use the GNU C compiler tool-chain. To use wide characters in paths the newer universal C runtime (UCRT) is needed. Because of this OpenModelica recently switched form MINGW64 to UCRT64 environment. There seems to be one step left to fix the issue for good.
But until the bug is fixed the only solution is to stick to printable ASCII characters in your path.

I think one could use a directory junction mklink /J c:\VirtualNameNoSpecialChars c:\Path\with\special\chars. Then use c:\VirtualNameNoSpecialChars in your OMEdit->Tools->Options->General->Working directory
